# How to hide user details in the Alexa companion app?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

For example, if the user says pin for the authentication it should not come as text in the Alexa companion app. As Alexa companion app contains all the interaction.

Comment: Is your concern the existence of the data or that the user that owns the device can see it?  If it is the former, the question should be framed around how to have Amazon destroy the content as well vs just not showing it.

Comment: If there is a possibility to hide security details it would be a good thing. I am not concerned for the existence of the data but the authentication details should never be stored in the plain text form or it should not be stored at all.

Comment: Being shown on the screen doesn't tell you anything about the persisted state.  Being on the physical phone is one risk, being in Amazon's cloud is another. Of course, easily visible in an app if somebody can log into your phone is very weak physical security, though you can't trust local encryption with key on the device. It is all about the size of the attack surface.